# Cache doesn't work, images are reloaded each time

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, browser-cache

I am building a very simple page here: http://www.wordjackpot.com
My problem appears in Google Chrome only, when I reload the page, the images are reloaded each time as if there's no cache, I'm not sure if the problem comes from my code or from chrome because for the example on stackoverflow.com images have http code 304 when I reload the page.
Then my question is: what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your return headers... you are explicitly telling the browsers to not cache.

This will be an apache (web server) setting.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4026
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Tue, 03 Feb 2015 14:33:44 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:300gp=R3396092545; path=/; expires=Tue, 03-Feb-2015 15:46:10 GMT
X-Cacheable:Not cacheable: no-cache
X-Geo:varn34.rbx5
X-Geo-Port:1011
X-Pad:avoid browser bug
```

Comment: But why ? Is it the default value ? I have to had headers through php ?

Comment: OK, I found why, my environment is set to "development" in OVH config and it disable caching. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at your HTTP Headers, you have no-cache all over it.